# How to get a screenshot directly into a variable when using R

Tags: r, screenshot, rmagick

I use R and the Magick package to process screenshots! Currently, I'm going through an external tool to get my screenshots. This tool gives me a file (png or other) that I have to reload to use it with Magick. Is there a package that would allow me to take screenshots (in whole or only partially) and to retrieve the image directly into a variable without going through an intermediate file? I found plenty of stuff for web-snapshots but nothing for a capture of my screen...
Thanks in advance

Comment: Try: `myImage <- readClipboard(format = 8, raw = TRUE)`

Comment: Alas it doesn't work. More specifically, I can't get there that way. Thanks for the proposal.